# RestSharp AddFile() and AddBody() in one request

Tags: http, rest, soa, restsharp

Is possible to add a Json Body and a file in a POST request in RestSharp?

```
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddFile("file", Writer,Guid.NewGuid() + ".pdf","application/pdf");
request.AddBody(model);
var response = (RestResponse)client.Execute(request);
```

I am hitting error when I try to send request using the code above.

> **Error Message**: This property cannot be set after writing has started.
>
> **StackTrace**
>
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_ContentLength(Int64 value)    at
>   RestSharp.Http.WriteRequestBody(HttpWebRequest webRequest)    at
>   RestSharp.Http.PostPutInternal(String method)    at
>   RestSharp.Http.AsPost(String httpMethod)    at
>   RestSharp.RestClient.DoExecuteAsPost(IHttp http, String method)    at
>   RestSharp.RestClient.Execute(IRestRequest request, String httpMethod,
>   Func`3 getResponse)